# AS3 - XML change element value not working?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm currently making a high scores table, and one of the high score tables is for a spelling quiz.

I have a local file called `highscores.xml`, which looks like this:

```
<highscores>
    <spelling>
        <first>0</first>
        <second>0</second>
        <third>0</third>
        <fourth>0</fourth>
        <fifth>0</fifth>
    </spelling>
</highscores>
```

and this is AS3 function that runs after I load the `highscores.xml` file:

```
function highScoresLoaded(e:Event)
{
    highScoresXML = new XML(urlLoader.data);
    highScoresArray = new Array();
    highScoresArray.push(highScoresXML.spelling.first);
    highScoresArray.push(highScoresXML.spelling.second);
    highScoresArray.push(highScoresXML.spelling.third);
    highScoresArray.push(highScoresXML.spelling.fourth);
    highScoresArray.push(highScoresXML.spelling.fifth);
    highScoresArray.push(points);
    highScoresArray = highScoresArray.sort(Array.DESCENDING);
    highScoresArray.pop();

    firstScoreTXT.text = highScoresArray[0];
    secondScoreTXT.text = highScoresArray[1];
    thirdScoreTXT.text = highScoresArray[2];
    fourthScoreTXT.text = highScoresArray[3];
    fifthScoreTXT.text = highScoresArray[4];

    highScoresXML.spelling.first = highScoresArray[0];
    highScoresXML.spelling.second = highScoresArray[1];
    highScoresXML.spelling.third = highScoresArray[2];
    highScoresXML.spelling.fourth = highScoresArray[3];
    highScoresXML.spelling.fifth = highScoresArray[4];

    trace(highScoresXML);
}
```

but the trace output at the end of a function goes like this(I've just scored 4250 on the quiz):

```
<highscores>
  <spelling>
    <first>4250</first>
    <second>0</second>
    <third>0</third>
    <first>4250</first>
    <fifth>0</fifth>
  </spelling>
</highscores>
```

When I delete this line it works fine:

```
highScoresXML.spelling.fourth = highScoresArray[3];
```

I'm not that good at programming and can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is what you need:

```
var highScoresXML:XML =<highscores>
    <spelling>
        <first>0</first>
        <second>0</second>
        <third>0</third>
        <fourth>0</fourth>
        <fifth>0</fifth>
    </spelling>
</highscores>;


var highScoresArray:Array = new Array();
var highScoresNamesArray:Array = new Array();

for (var i:uint = 0; i<highScoresXML.spelling.children().length(); i++){
    highScoresArray.push(highScoresXML.spelling.children()[i]);
    highScoresNamesArray.push(highScoresXML.spelling.children()[i].name() );
}

highScoresArray.push(100);
highScoresArray = highScoresArray.sort(Array.DESCENDING);
highScoresArray.pop();

highScoresXML.spelling = new XML();

for(i=0; i<highScoresNamesArray.length;i++)
    highScoresXML.spelling.appendChild("<"+highScoresNamesArray[i]+">"
                                                  +highScoresArray[i]
                                          +"</"+highScoresNamesArray[i]+">");
```